# Odd behavior from FragmentStatePagerAdapter getItem

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have the following `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` inner class:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            /*
             * Here we are going to return the correct type of fragment for each
             * of the pages
             */
            switch(position){
            case 0:
                return MainListFragment.init(position); 
            case 1:
                return MainListFragment.init(position);
            case 2:
                return MainListFragment.init(position); 
            default:
                return MainListFragment.init(position); 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
                    //breakpoint set here
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_main_feed).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_settings).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_about).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And there is some really odd behavior. I set a couple break points in my debugger to what is going on and here is what I've found. The first time I launch the app it will hit the breakpoint once, then I hit 'continue' and it hits it again, essentially hitting the switch statement twice before the app even loads. Once the app loads, only the second page (page 1, or the middle) will display the list data.

The other odd thing is that as I scroll, the `position` variable never is correct. When I start on 0 and go to 1, the breakpoint is hit and position is 2, then when I scroll to 2, the breakpoint is NOT hit. I go back to 1, the breakpoint is hit, but position is 0, not 1.

I'm confused about what is going on and why I'm not getting list data on all my pages. Can someone clarify what's going on?

Essentially what I want to do is to have different list views depending on what page I'm on. Am I doing this the right way, or is there another way I should go about this.

Comment: I'm confused as to why all your switch cases are doing the same thing. Are you planning on having custom logic in each case?

Comment: Yes. At the moment I'm just trying to make sure the process works. Eventually, they will each load a different list.